# how to uninstall tomcat from AWS linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-web-services

What is the equivalent of `sudo yum install tomcat7 tomcat7-webapps` but for uninstalling tomcat7? Is there a straight forward method and that leaves no trace behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo yum remove tomcat7 tomcat7-webapps`.